# DVD drive stepper motors with polulu a4988 on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

I am new to arduino, I started learning about it today and i'm stuck. I ripped out a small stepper motor from an old DVD drive. I got a polulu a4988 driver and I have wired it up as follows:

[image]

```
/*     Simple Stepper Motor Control Exaple Code
 *      
 *  by Dejan Nedelkovski, www.HowToMechatronics.com
 *  
 */
// defines pins numbers
const int stepPin = 3; 
const int dirPin = 4; 

void setup() {
  // Sets the two pins as Outputs
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
  // Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
  for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
  }
  delay(1000); // One second delay

  digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW); //Changes the rotations direction
  // Makes 400 pulses for making two full cycle rotation
  for(int x = 0; x < 400; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

But nothing happens, the motor doesn't even vibrate. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Check the data sheet and see if you can truly leave all of those pins on the left side unconnected.  Additionaly, you need the /sleep pin high - you seem to be hoping there is a /pullup resistor on the reset line which will accomplish that for both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Pololu's website, the VMOT pin needs at least 8V to function. Try a 12V **switching** (important!) wall wart supply that can supply at least 1A instead of your USB supply. Avoid supplies that can deliver currents >3A, as they are overkill for a small stepper motor and can be dangerous if shorted. Be sure to put a large (100uF is good) capacitor across that supply to prevent voltage spikes. To prevent damaging the motor from the higher voltage, follow the information Pololu provides on setting the current limit and set it to about 350mA. If you notice the motor is too hot to touch, try 200mA.

Comment: thank you! I found a psu for an external hard drive which outputs 12v and 2A. Would this be suitable?

Comment: That is almost definitely a switching supply and it should be suitable. Make sure that you pay attention to the polarity when hooking it up.

Comment: Great, thank you. I still haven't got it to work, my arduino switches off for some reason. Not sure why though.

Comment: I recently bought one of these and it had an internal short from the STEP pin to ground. This caused my Arduino to shut off too. Check all the pins connected to the Arduino with a multimeter to see if there are any shorts to ground, VCC, or VMOT. Post a picture of your soldering and wiring too. The Arduino should not be shutting off if this is wired correctly

Comment: Oh I see, i'll do it as soon as i get home tomorrow! thanks for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: It turns out my arduino is fried. Not sure when/how that happened. I ordered a clone now and i'll try it again and see if it works! Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it the entire arduino or just one of the pins connected to the A4988?

Comment: Before you connect it to the arduino, connect the motor, hook up VMOT and its ground pin to your 12V supply, connect Vcc and its ground pin to your USB 5V supply, connect RESET to SLEEP, connect DIR to Vcc, put a 10K resistor from STEP to GND, and wire a pushbutton from STEP to Vcc. Turn on the power supplies and press the pushbutton. If the motor does not move, it could be that the motor is wired incorrectly (likely), the motor is defective (unlikely) or the A4988 module is damaged (somewhat likely). If you can't get it working in this configuration, contact Pololu customer service.